# use member function of socket class or common function in Boost::asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am learning Boost::asio socket; I saw some [examples](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_12_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime7.html), where they use the member function of socket class to read and receive messages, or use the boost::asio common function which passes the socket as the first param.

So I am wondering what the difference is between the two approaches? thanks!

```
//one kind
tcp::socket sock;
sock.async_write_some(***);

//another kind
boost::asio::async_write(socket,***);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async_write` as static function guarantees that all data in buffer 
is written before this function returns.

`async_write_some` as function member guarantees that at least one byte
is written from buffer before this function ends.

So if you want to use `async_write_some` you need to provide more code
to handle the situation when not all data from buffer was written.

Suppose you have string with 10 bytes, it is your buffer and you want to ensure
all buffer is send:

```
// Pseudocode:

string str;
// add 10 bytes to str
SIZE = 10;
int writtenBytes = 0;
socket.async_write_some (buffer(str.c_str(),SIZE), makeCallback());

void callback (
    error_code ec,
    size_t transferredBytes)
{
    // check errors

    // [1]
    writtenBytes += transferredBytes;
    if (writtenBytes == SIZE)
         return;

    // call async_write_some 
    socket.async_write_some (buffer(str.c_str()+writtenBytes,SIZE-writtenBytes),makeCallback());
}
```

in callback *[1]* you need to check how many bytes were written,
if result is different from `SIZE` you need to call `async_write_some` again
to send the remainder of data and so on, your callback may be invoked many times.

The use of `async_write` is simpler:

```
string str; // add 10 bytes
async_write (buffer(str.c_str(),SIZE),makeCallback());

void callback() {
  // check errors
  [1]
}
```

if no errors occured in `[1]` you know that all data was sent.

Comment: Thanks so much, according to your answer, async_write function seems a good choice, but what is the  meaning of existence  of `async_write_some` and `async_read_some`?

Comment: Hmm, nice question. *Boost Asio* is wrapper for API which implements berkeley sockets, for example under linux you can use `recv` function which also doesn't guarantee that all buffer is received, it can return less bytes  than was passed as argument to read. So `async_read_some` follows such behaviour.